# stange error with Behat and Mink on Sf2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, behat, mink

I'm using Behat,mink in my Symfony2 project,so I follow those tutorials to make installation :

http://extensions.behat.org/symfony2/ , http://extensions.behat.org/symfony2/migrating_from_2.3_to_2.4.html

but when I run this command `php behat.phar --init "@YouBundleName"`,I get this very strange error :

```
PHP Warning:  require(Behat\MinkExtension\Extension): failed to open stream: No such   file or directory in phar:///var/www/project/behat.phar/src/Behat/Behat  /Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 112
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Behat\MinkExtension\Extension' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in phar:///var/www/project/behat.phar/src/Behat/Behat/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 112
```

I'm sure I installed the last version of behat and mink mentionned in the second link above and then I made `php composer.phar unpdate` and `cache clear` too,but still the same error?

Comment: What have you got in your behat.yml? I see you've downloaded phar archive of behat, have you done the same with mink? Why not simply using composer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Forgot you need to install `behat/mink-extension` as well as `behat/mink`. For example you might need to run:

```
php composer.phar require behat/mink-extension:*
```

Worked for me.

By the way, looks like you got confused by the two installation methods, phar vs composer. I'd go with the composer route because it's easier to update and manage versions. This would mean running `php bin/behat ...` instead of `php behat.phar ...`.